# spark datame column and row above 2gb

Tags: python, apache-spark, delta-lake

I'm using spark with delta lake (python) where I read a 10 gb json file.

This file contains 5 columns, but one of them is a struct column that contains more than 100 columns, including string, long, array and struct types.

As I am using delta lake, I would like to save this dataframe entirely in a bronze table of delta lake.

However, a buffer error occurs, it cannot be above 2gb. I suppose that the column or row cannot be larger than 2gb. However, I suppose this is a spark limitation that was fixed in previous versions, but it still persists in version 3.2.1.

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

How can I store large files in delta lake bronze tables without performing datafrane transformations to store in delta lake bronze tables?

Thank you very much

Carlos